# Error - Failed to register Fiddler as the system proxy

Tags: fiddlercore, fiddler-dev

When I try to run FiddleApplication.Startup(startupConfig)

```
FiddlerCoreStartupSettings startupSettings = newFiddlerCoreStartupSettingsBuilder()
                    .ListenOnPort(0)
                    .RegisterAsSystemProxy()
                    .DecryptSSL()
                    .Build();

FiddlerApplication.Startup(startupSettings);
```

In my log events I see:

```
Starting FiddlerCore/4.6.20191.7809 (NoSAZ)...
** LogString: !WARNING: The DefaultLAN Gateway information could not be obtained.
** NotifyUser: Error - Failed to register Fiddler as the system proxy.
```

I'm running the process as administrator.

Note: When I run the normal Fiddler UI application everything works fine. Even running an older FiddlerCore version (2.3) is able to register itself as the system proxy.

P.S - I also see a warning in Visual Studio - "Please use `Telerik.NetworkConnections.NetworkConnectionsManager` to register the FiddlerCore Proxy as the system proxy." But I couldn't find any documentation/examples using `NetworkConnectionsManager` and I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: Do you have the Telerik.NetworkConnections.dll and Telerik.NetworkConnections.Windows.dll present in your application directory? There is a sample application in the FiddlerCore installer, which can be used as a starting point.

Comment: If it helps anything, this issue only happens to me when using the portable version made available through https://stackoverflow.com/a/21756167/4829915 - this means the installation is needed in order to register the system proxy. Any idea why or how?